# how to retrieve the image path and display it in html using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

my code is like this

```
    <%@ include file="getcon.jsp"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>View Image Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<!-- main content -->
<%
ResultSet rs=null;
try
{

rs=st.executeQuery("select * from file1");

while(rs.next())
{
%>
<table width="70%" height="160" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<!-- Mention Directory where your images has been saved-->

<td><img src="<%=rs.getString("file_path") %>" alt="image" /></td>
<td> <%out.print(rs.getString(1)); %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<%
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.print(""+e.getMessage());
}
%>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

i am able to see  the image path from the second   column of table but am not able to see the image what are the reasons for this can someone help me please
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest your quotes like that. Try something like:

```
<img src="<%rs.getString('file_path'); %>" alt="image" />
```

or maybe

```
<img src="<%=rs.getString('file_path'); %>" alt="image" />
```

I don't remember which.

Answer (score 0):

I presume images' paths are incorrect.
Best you can do is to display rendered page's source code, by right clicking to the page in the browser and showing the source code (In most browser). 
Then search for the tag  .../>
Then you will understand why your path is incorrect.
I presume you are missing a slash or something like.

Comment: `code` <td><img src="C:\Users\suhail\Documents\NetBeansProjects\new\web\UploadedFiles\Lighthouse.jpg"  /></td> `code`